# React native event hover and active on the View

Tags: react-native, view, hover

How can I manage to intercept an event of type `hover/active` on a view.
I would like to make sure that you pass on a hover badge change the color of the badge background and the color of the text, same thing for the active type event.

Can you give me some advice?

If there is a way to do it.

I thought I was using TouchableHighlight.

[image]

Link: [snack](https://snack.expo.io/HJswM-2iS)

Code:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
    import Constants from 'expo-constants';

    function Badge({ name, url, backgroundColor, color, onPress }) {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor || '#e5f1f6',
            width: 60,
            height: 100,
            borderRadius: 30,
            padding: 5,
            margin: 2,
            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOffset: {
              width: 0,
              height: 2,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 0.25,
            shadowRadius: 3.84,
            elevation: 5,
          }}>
          <Image
            style={{ width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 25 }}
            source={{
              uri: url,
            }}
          />
          <Text
            style={{
              color: color || '#5490a7',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              marginTop: 10,
            }}>
            {name}
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Badge
              name="BL"
              url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/64/Brie_Larson_%28cropped%29.jpg/170px-Brie_Larson_%28cropped%29.jpg"
              backgroundColor="#2196f3"
              backgroundColorActive="#ed5653"
              color="#ffffff"
            />
            <Badge
              name="JVT"
              url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Yulia_Tymoshenko_2018_Vadim_Chuprina.jpg/920px-Yulia_Tymoshenko_2018_Vadim_Chuprina.jpg"
              backgroundColor="#ed5653"
              backgroundColorActive="#ed5653"
              color="#ffffff"
            />
            <Badge
              name="AA"
              url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Alberto_Angela%2C2013.jpg/220px-Alberto_Angela%2C2013.jpg"
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
        flexDirection: 'row',
      },
    });
```

Comment: Assuming you are talking about `react-native-web`, then you might wanna take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/necolas/1c494e44e23eb7f8c5864a2fac66299a)

Comment: You can also check [this](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/205).